# Rectangle is not drawing the bullish engulfing pattern

Tags: mql4, trading, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4

I wrote the following code to look through the last 100 candlesticks and draw a rectangle around a bullish engulfing candlestick patterns. I hope extend it for bearish engulfing pattern too. I don't know why, but the rectangles don't draw. Please take a look at the code below

```
bool isBullishEngulfing(int current)  {

   if((iClose(_Symbol,0,current) > iOpen(_Symbol,0,current)) && (iClose(_Symbol,0,current + 1) < iOpen(_Symbol,0,current + 1))  && 
      (iOpen(_Symbol,0,current) < iClose(_Symbol,0,current + 1)) && (iClose(_Symbol,0,current) > iOpen(_Symbol,0,current + 1)))
         return true;
      return false;         

}

void showRectangles() {

   for (int i=100;i<=1;i--)   {
      if(isBullishEngulfing(i)) {

        drawBullRectangle(i,iHigh(_Symbol,0,i),iLow(_Symbol,0,i));
    }
   }
}

bool drawBullRectangle(int candleInt,const double top,const double bottom)
{
    const datetime starts=iTime(_Symbol,0,candleInt); 
    const datetime ends=starts+PeriodSeconds()*Numbars; //Numbars shows how long the rectangle should draw
    const string name=prefix+"_"+(candleInt>0?"DEMAND":"SUPPLY")+"_"+TimeToString(starts);

    if(!ObjectCreate(0,name,OBJ_RECTANGLE,0,0,0,0,0))
    {
        printf("%i %s: failed to create %s. error=%d",__LINE__,__FILE__,name,_LastError);
        return false;
    }
    ObjectSetInteger(0,name,OBJPROP_TIME1,starts);
    ObjectSetInteger(0,name,OBJPROP_TIME2,ends);
    ObjectSetDouble(0,name,OBJPROP_PRICE1,top);
    ObjectSetDouble(0,name,OBJPROP_PRICE2,bottom);

    ObjectSetInteger(0,name,OBJPROP_COLOR, clrAqua);

   ObjectSetInteger(0,name,OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,name,OBJPROP_WIDTH,1);

   ObjectSetInteger(0,name,OBJPROP_FILL, true);

    return true;
}

void OnDeinit(const int reason){ObjectsDeleteAll(0,prefix);}
void OnTick()
{
    if(!isNewBar())
        return;     //not necessary but waste of time to check every second


    showRectangles();
}

bool isNewBar()
{
   static datetime lastbar;
   datetime curbar = (datetime)SeriesInfoInteger(_Symbol,_Period,SERIES_LASTBAR_DATE);
   if(lastbar != curbar)
   {
      lastbar = curbar;
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

I would appreciate help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is mainly in the loop, it should be `for (int i=100;i>=1;i--)`

The other *"possible"* error is in the logic of the`isBullishEngulfing()` function.

Usually, the Close of the previous bar is equal to the Open of the current bar, so the following condition doesn't get fulfilled(most of the time)

```
iOpen(_Symbol,0,current) < iClose(_Symbol,0,current + 1)
```

(So, I suggest to remove this line, but this is just a suggestion, note there are occasions that your condition get fulfilled as well)